# Circle Detection Image Processing boolean output

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on implementing the hough transform for circle detection in an image in a camera preview. The image is most likely going to look as follows after some thresholding.

[image]

I was just introduced to hough transform and I am using the following code.

```
[rows,columns] = size(circle);
acc = zeros(rows,columns);

r=9;

for x=1:columns
    for y=1:rows
        if(circle(y,x)==0)
            for ang=0:360
                t=(ang*pi)/180;
                x0=round(x-r*cos(t));
                y0=round(y-r*sin(t));
                if(x0<columns && x0>0 && y0<rows && y0>0)
                    acc(y0,x0)=acc(y0,x0)+1;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How do I use the accumulator to return a boolean value(e.g true if there is a circle else false).

Please do let me know if there are any simpler ways I can look into than using Hough Transform. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is already a matlab function for this problem you could use
http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html

or do you just want to write the hough-transform yourself?

Comment: I want to do it myself since I am going to port the code to a different platform. Im just using matlab to develop it.